# swift repl not working in windows subsystem for linux

Tags: swift, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Swift for Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows (WSSL) using the instructions on the swift website: https://swift.org/download/#using-downloads

It seems that it's recognizing the version, but when I just type `swift` to enter the REPL, it seems to get stuck and I can't exit out of the shell without just quitting the terminal:

```
allen@LAPTOP-C6O7O7KR:~$ swift --version
Swift version 5.0.1 (swift-5.0.1-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
allen@LAPTOP-C6O7O7KR:~$ swift
let x = 5;
print(x)
;
exit
^C

:q
:q
exit
^C
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Did you ever get around this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: nope not yet, i'll post something here if I find a solution

Comment: I have the same issue here.

Comment: A year later and the same issue...

Answer (score 2):

I assume it's related to https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/688

```
ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```